# How do I remove index.aspx from a url using web.config?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, rackspace

How would one redirect from www.example.com/section/index.aspx to www.example.com/section using rewrite rules in web.config? It would also have to work for various levels such as www.example.com/parent/child

*Noting that I do not have access to the server. I can basically just edit the web.config file and tell the server to rebuild the application.

Comment: Can you confirm which version of IIS you're using, and what if any URL Rewrite modules you've installed? For example are you using the IIS 7 URL Rewrite Module?

Comment: is it only index.aspx in every directory that you need removed? Have you looked into using the MVC for ASP.NET?

Comment: @Justin C: That's a fairly major change to the application for something that can be a simple HTTPModule fix ;)

Comment: Server is running IIS 7 and not running any 3rd party rewrite modules. I only need to remove index.aspx from the url to get past the load balancer.

Comment: I agree that MVC is a huge change for the application, I was just trying to understand what steps ornj has taken since the goal described fits the MVC model so well.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to use the [IIS7 URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) - but you would need to install this on the server.  It's pretty easy to use and powerful at the same time.  It may already be installed if you're hosted, because although it's not installed by default, it is from Microsoft and pretty frequently used.

If you're on 2.0 or greater of asp.net, you can add a `urlMappings` section to the web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
        <add url="~/Section" mappedUrl="~/Section/index.aspx"/>
    </arlMappings>
</system.web>
```

But this has some issues : Firstly, if the URL requested isn't handled by the ASP.Net module, or isn't delivered to your application, the rewrite never happens.  This could occur because you aren't hitting a ".aspx" file, for example.  Also, in some configurations, the file you request needs to exist.    Another issue is that there are no wildcard rules supported, so you would have to add rules to rewrite all possible paths individually.

And finally, there are asp.net rewrite httpmodules you could drop in the bin directory and add to your web.config.  Here's some (possibly outdated) options by ScottGu for [url rewriting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: Can you suggest in case we have url /folder/index.asp?parameter=val and needs to be converted to /folder/val/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably massively disgusting but by creating rules for each possible level I was able to rewrite all paths dropping index.aspx from the url.

starting with

```
<rule name="Migrate to PHP">
 <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+).aspx"/>
 <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/"/>
</rule>
```

and ending with

```
<rule name="Migrate to PHP all the way">
 <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+).aspx"/>
 <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}/{R:4}"/>
</rule>
```